# VirtualBox: two or more OS in one usb disk "unmountable boot volume"

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, virtualbox, partitioning

My goal:

For education purposes I've been asked to install Windows and Linux on the same usb and be able to boot them from virtual box

My problem:

Windows crashes with "unmountable boot volume"

The process I've made this far:

I have an usb disk 1tb with 3 partitions

- first for personal files with 900gb(NTFS)
- Linux partition 50gb(ext4)
- Windows partition 50gb(NTFS)

Those os were installed in that order.

For Linux:

when I reached the intallation type, used "others"
Defined the second partition "dev/sda/2" as root
and for the Device boot loader installation "dev/sda"

For the VB vmdk I used this command:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "C:\LinuxPath.vmdk" -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive1 -partitions 2 -relative
```

creating a Hardisk with 1tb size but 50gb actual size

[image: show]

AND ALL THIS WORKS!

now for Windows:

when installing via VB Windows I have this problem:

[image: error1]

which tells me it cant install on partition 3 of disk 0 (my external hdd)

So my solution was  "WinToUsb" selecting the corresponding partition.

then with the next command routed the vmdk to that partition:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "C:\winxpath.vmdk" -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive1 -partitions 3 -relative
```

But now when it comes to boot the Windows VM ,

appears the Windows booting logo and then:

[image: error2]

Is there anything I am missing?